# MySQL export into outfile : sql is not working.File is not created at the specified location

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL export into outfile : sql is not working.Below code executed successfully but file is not created at the specified location.

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'C:\\Users\\sam\\Desktop\\NewDBChange\\NEW_TEST_ENV\\RegistrationTableData.sql'
FROM `registration`
WHERE created_date > '2016-10-26 15:17:14';
```

Comment: where is the file created? Are you executing this from a remote command line? That is, the cli on your pc, the server on a remote location?

Comment: I am executing from SQLyog community.When i try to execute 2nd time. It is throwing errror.Error Code: 1086
File 'C:\Users\sudhanshum\Desktop\NewDBChange\TEST_ENV_PROMO\NEW_TEST_ENV\tripRegistrationTableData.sql' already exists

Comment: If you want to create the resulting file on some other host than the server host, you normally cannot use SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE since there is no way to write a path to the file relative to the server host's file system.

However, if the MySQL client software is installed on the remote machine, you can instead use a client command such as mysql -e "SELECT ..." > file_name to generate the file on the client host.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html

Comment: Destination file is .sql. is it correct of it should be .txt/.csv?

Comment: @Biswabid, .sql extension should not be a problem, it should create a text file on server and "not on client from where sql is executed".